# Waveshare 2CH RS232 HAT on Raspberry pi 4 not sending nor receiving message

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, serial, uart, hat

Hi Raspberry pi enthusiast,

Recently i'm using 2 Channel RS232 Hat from waveshare placed on top of raspberry pi 4. And i already follow all the instruction on [this waveshare's wiki](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/2-CH_RS232_HAT). but, until right now i can't send nor receive message on /dev/ttySC0 and /dev/ttySC1 eventhough they're already in /dev. please kindly help me on this problem.

the details are:

```
uname -a
```

outputs of the raspbian are

```
Linux raspberrypi 5.15.82-v7l+ #1605 SMP Thu Dec 8 15:21:38 GMT 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

and `ls -la /dev | grep -i ttySC*` are

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root           5 Dec 13 01:56 serial0 -> ttyS0
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  64 Dec 13 01:56 ttyS0
crw-rw----   1 root dialout 236,   0 Dec 13 16:41 ttySC0
crw-rw----   1 root dialout 236,   1 Dec 13 01:56 ttySC1
```

i already follow the instruction to add line /boot/config.txt

```
[all]
enable_uart=1
gpu_mem=204
dtoverlay=sc16is752-spi1,int_pin=24
```

and reboot the raspberry so /dev/ttySC0 and /dev/ttySC1 appeared in /dev
i also checked the `dmesg | grep -i ttySC*` and it came like this

```
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 video=HDMI-A-1:1280x720M@60 smsc95xx.macaddr=E4:5F:01:F5:97:92 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=81fdf81e-02 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
[    1.716024] printk: console [ttyS0] disabled
[    1.716145] fe215040.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0xfe215040 (irq = 36, base_baud = 62500000) is a 16550
[    1.716353] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
[   10.419176] spi1.0: ttySC1 at I/O 0x1 (irq = 82, base_baud = 921600) is a SC16IS752
[  607.883507] sc16is7xx spi1.0: ttySC0 (0): invalid RTS setting, using RTS_ON_SEND instead
[ 1280.397042] sc16is7xx spi1.0: ttySC0 (0): invalid RTS setting, using RTS_ON_SEND instead
```

the tutorial on waveshare wiki include python test script that send string over /dev/ttySC0 to /dev/ttySC1. but no luck till now, it doesn't send or receive anything, the TX RX indicator led is not even blinking.
the test script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import serial
import os
import sys
import logging
import time

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
libdir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))), 'lib')
if os.path.exists(libdir):
    sys.path.append(libdir)

from waveshare_2_CH_RS232_HAT import config

ser1 = config.config(Baudrate=460800, dev = "/dev/ttySC0")
ser2 = config.config(Baudrate=460800, dev = "/dev/ttySC1")
data = ''

try:
    while(1):
        ser1.Uart_SendString('Waveshare 2-CH RS232 HAT\r\n')
        data_t = ser2.Uart_ReceiveString(26)
        print(data_t)
        if(data_t == 'Waveshare 2-CH RS232 HAT\r\n'):
            print("CH1 sends CH2 reception successfully")
        ser2.Uart_SendString('Waveshare 2-CH RS232 HAT\r\n')
        data_t = ser1.Uart_ReceiveString(26)
        print(data_t)
        if(data_t == 'Waveshare 2-CH RS232 HAT\r\n'):
            print("CH2 sends CH1 reception successfully")
        time.sleep(1)


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    logging.info("ctrl + c:")
    exit()
```

the putput should be
[image]
but i only got /dev/ttySC0 and /dev/ttySC1 and not the message

and here is my setup that instructed to connect ttySC0 and ttySC1
[image: see the power led is up but tx rx is not blinked]
here is the close up waveshare 2CH RS232 HAT

[image]
it has sc16is752 that connected to spi1 (not i2c) and sp3232 IC.

the dmesg output says

```
[   10.419176] spi1.0: ttySC1 at I/O 0x1 (irq = 82, base_baud = 921600) is a SC16IS752
[  607.883507] sc16is7xx spi1.0: ttySC0 (0): invalid RTS setting, using RTS_ON_SEND instead
[ 1280.397042] sc16is7xx spi1.0: ttySC0 (0): invalid RTS setting, using RTS_ON_SEND instead
```

what does it mean? and what should i do if `ttySC0 (0): invalid RTS setting, using RTS_ON_SEND instead` appear. please help.

Comment: Is the userid you're using to run that Python program on the `dialout` group?

Comment: well i used it using sudo. sudo python test.py. but still not working

Comment: Has your DB9 cable 1:1 connection? If yes, maybe you are connecting Rx to RX and TX to TX at the same time

Comment: And what D-sub 9 to D-sub 9 cable have you used, its not specified!